# calling methods without having reference

Tags: java

if i want to call multiple methods of a one class from another class can i call them by using only 'new classname()' without catching it in class reference?

```
public class Example {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new pqr().a=5;
        new pqr().b=10;
        new pqr().display();
    }
}
class pqr
{
        int a,b;

        public void display()
        {
                System.out.println(a+" "+b);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This creates three new objects. Not just one.

```
new pqr().a=5;
new pqr().b=10;
new pqr().display();
```

One object with a = 5 and another with b = 10.

Remember you are not working with one object.

Whenever you use **new** keyword. JVM creates a new object.

Comment: and display won't reference either of them

Answer (score 3):

> if i want to call multiple methods of a one class from another class can i call them by using only 'new classname()' without catching it in class reference?

It's not clear what you mean by "catching it" but you *are* using a reference... you're just not assigning it to a variable.

In your example, you're creating three different objects - the calculation on your final line just prints 0, because you've only set `a` and `b` in other objects. If you want to use a *single* object for multiple operations, you'll *either* need to store the reference in a variable, or those operations will have to return "this", allowing you to chain method calls together:

```
class Sample {
    private int a,b;

    public void display() {

        System.out.println(a+" "+b);
    }    

    public Sample setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    public Sample setB(int b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }
}

...

new Sample().setA(5).setB(10).display();
```

This sort of chaining for setters is common in the builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Builder](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2) pattern if you want something like that:

```
NutritionFacts cocaCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8).
    calories(100).sodium(35).carbohydrate(27).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The builder pattern is one possibility. The another one is to have static properties so all object will share it's values.

```
static int a,b;
```